# How to get previous jTabbedPane overlap

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have problem with getting id of previous overlap of jTabbedPane.

```
ksiegiWieczysteTabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            KsiegaWieczystaPanel księgaWieczystaPanel = (KsiegaWieczystaPanel) ksiegiWieczysteTabbedPane.getSelectedComponent();
            if(MainApp.main.showPytanieBox("Czy chcesz zapisać zmiany?")) {       
                if(księgaWieczystaPanel != null) {
                    księgaWieczystaPanel.zapiszWszystko();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Now I can get the actual clicked overlap but do I have chance to get the previous one? Assume I have 3 overlaps: A,B,C. Now if I click A it is easy to recognize that it is A by `ksiegiWieczysteTabbedPane.getSelectedComponent()` but when I click B is it possible to know that the previous overlap which was selected were A?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I note you have edited the question to remove a line of code. Any chance of seeing an edit with an MCVE/SSCCE any time soon?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I tried to explain the problem as briefly as I could.

Comment: *"I tried to explain the problem as briefly as I could."* Yes, I get the 'minimal' part, what about the CVE parts? Note that a fully formed MCVE can be >100 LOC if all the lines are really needed to make it a CVE.

Comment: You mean I should post the code which will work and you can copy and paste? I thought there can be an easy answer, that's why I didn't make the new program to just present the problem

Comment: One possibility would be to maintain some kind of variable which maintained what ever information you wanted to know about the last selected tab, each time the `ChangeListener` was called, you would first check the last properties before updating them to the current (now selected) tab

Comment: Yes, that's how I made it. I use integer which keep previous index. I just thought that it can be make nicer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know this is how to `set` and `get` selected `index` in `jtabbedPane`

```
JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();

// this represents previously selected tab.
int selectedIndex = pane.getSelectedIndex(); 

//with this method you can change the selected index.
pane.setSelectedIndex(yourIndex);
```